# Format output of query

Tags: sql, bash, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am running SnowQL queries like so -

```
snowsql -u user -w cluster -d db -s public -a "account" -r admin -q "SELECT bucket FROM buckets GROUP BY bucket" | while read bucket_name_var ; 
do
if [ ! -z "$bucket_name_var" ]
then
fi
done
```

This is the output it produces -

```
* SnowSQL * v1.2.20
Type SQL statements or !help
+-------------+
| BUCKET
|-------------|
| 960         |
+-------------+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.927s
Goodbye!
```

How do I get this output instead -

```
960
```

I want this output so that `bucket_name_var` variable will only have output values (e.g. 960) that can be looped because right now everything from the version of Snowflake to goodbye is being looped on.

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: What will happen if you use the ```output_format```, e. g. ```-o header=false```,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your snowsql command to get raw output:

```
-o friendly=false -o header=false -o timing=false -o output_format=plain
```

Reference: https://snowflakecommunity.force.com/s/article/SnowSQL-display-raw-result-of-a-query